# Items can’t be copied to “folder name” because you don’t have permission to read them

Tags: macos, permission

When trying to copy files to a network drive (external hard drive via Router by way of SMB) from MacBook Pro, I get the following:

```
Items can’t be copied to “folder name” because you don’t have permission to read them.
```

I ran `ls -@Odeln /Volumes/[folder name]` in Terminal and this came back:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 0  0  - 16384
```

I have set all `rw` permissions for users from my MacBook Pro and on the external hard drive, and I'm still getting the same error.

Has anyone else had this issue and been able to fix it?

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Now, unless I'm missing something, the message isn't reporting you lack authorization to *write* to ` /Volumes/[folder name]`, it's that you don't have authorization to *read* the files you want to copy. I suggest you check on the ownership of those files and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I guess I'm kind of confused by your question. All I know is when I try to copy items from my local MacBook Pro desktop to the server's folder, I get:

'The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items.'

I can drag files from the server folder to my local MacBook Pro desktop fine but can't do the reverse.

Comment: Aha, so it's a *server* on the other end... I thought you were trying to copy files to a network-based external hard drive. Take a look at the following, and see if it fits your situation: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113383/permissions-issue-when-copying-files-over-smb-to-server-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks

Comment: No you are correct. I guess I'm just calling it a "server" because of how I connect to it via the "Go" menu. But yes I am trying to copy files to a external hard drive that is connected to my router and it's giving me the stated error above.

Comment: Oh, you meant it as in "Go --> Connect to Server..." Right. So, to fix the problem we must determine who the system considers the owner(s) of these items: A.) The problematic files on your MBP's Desktop, and B.) The remote folder you want to copy them to. You can find out easily enough in the Finder by highlighting one or more of them and then by either using "Get Info" from the Finder's "File" menu or by typing `command-I`. At the bottom of each of the Info windows under "Sharing & Permissions" will be a table of names and privileges. Collect the information and add it to your original post.

Comment: Picture has now been posted. Please let me know if this is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Are the permissions correct? I believe they are.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue.

I checked the permissions in "Get Info" for the source and target folders - both said I could "Read & Write" as my user.

After disabling/enabling the share and rebooting the network node it was connected to - which I *don't think* helped - what I found was that was connected as my "reader" user.  So, in Finder, I selected "Disconnect" and "Connect as..." and connected with my "readwrite" user. Et voilà, I could copy as per usual.

Here's a screenshot of the top of Finder, with a tab open on the mounted network share. Note the "Connected as: [...]" and the "Disconnect" button.

[image]

Maybe this will help someone?  Maybe it was the node reboot that helped?!